# Why does du report a size of 0 for some non-empty files on a HFS+ partition?

Tags: osx, disk-usage, hfs+

What is the explanation for the difference:

```
$ ls -l /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  15730 11 jui 15:02 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist

$ du -sh /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist
0B     /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Once the file is copied in my home folder, `ls` and `du` report the same number.

```
$ cp /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist .
$ du -sh Info.plist; ls -l Info.plist
16K Info.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 ant  staff  15730 17 oct 16:53 Info.plist
```

Both directories are on this partition ( / )

```
diskutil  info /
Device Identifier:        disk0s2
Device Node:              /dev/disk0s2
Part of Whole:            disk0
Device / Media Name:      ml2013

Volume Name:              OSX.10.8
Escaped with Unicode:     OSX.10.8

Mounted:                  Yes
Mount Point:              /
Escaped with Unicode:     /

File System Personality:  Journaled HFS+
Type (Bundle):            hfs
Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
Journal:                  Journal size 40960 KB at offset 0xc83000
Owners:                   Enabled
```

Here is the output of stat:

```
$ stat  Info.plist
16777218 8780020 -rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 0 15730 "Oct 17 17:47:12 2013" \ 
"Jun 11 15:02:17 2013" "Jun 11 15:02:17 2013" "Apr 27 11:49:34 2013"\ 
4096 0 0x20 Info.plist
```

Comment: Once the file is copied where?

Comment: @terdon See my edit.

Comment: Are both directories on hfs+ filesystems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may have found something:

The ls command on OS X has this switch:

```
  -O      Include the file flags in a long (-l) output.
```

The result is:

```
$ ls -O Info.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  compressed 15730 11 jui 15:02 Info.plist
```

I just checked (experimentally) that `du` always reports `0` for HFS+ compressed files.

Copying compressed files uncompress them; so logically `du` reports the correct file on a copied, uncompressed file.

[Here is an explanation](http://wiki.sleuthkit.org/index.php?title=HFS) for the behaviour of `du`:

### HFS+ File Compression

> In Mac OS X 10.6, Apple introduced file compression in HFS+.
>   Compression is most often used for files installed as part of Mac OS
>   X; user files are typically not compressed (but certainly can be!).
>   Reading and writing compressed files is transparent as far as Apple's
>   file system APIs.
>
> Compressed files have an empty data fork. This means that forensic
>   tools not aware of HFS+ file compression (including TSK before 4.0.0)
>   will not see any data associated with a compressed file!

There is also a discussion on this subject in `Mac OS X and iOS Internals: To the Apple's Core` by Jonathan Levin , in chapter 16: To B(-Tree) or not to be - The HFS+ file systems.

Also [afsctool](https://github.com/diimdeep/afsctool) may help see which files are compressed in a folder.

```
$ afsctool -v /Applications/Safari.app/
/Applications/Safari.app/.:
Number of HFS+ compressed files: 1538
Total number of files: 2247
Total number of folders: 144
Total number of items (number of files + number of folders): 2391
Folder size (uncompressed; reported size by Mac OS 10.6+ Finder): 29950329 bytes / 34.7 MB (megabytes) / 33.1 MiB (mebibytes)
Folder size (compressed - decmpfs xattr; reported size by Mac OS 10.0-10.5 Finder): 21287197 bytes / 23.8 MB (megabytes) / 22.7 MiB (mebibytes)
Folder size (compressed): 22694835 bytes / 25.2 MB (megabytes) / 24 MiB (mebibytes)
Compression savings: 24.2%
Approximate total folder size (files + file overhead + folder overhead): 26353338 bytes / 26.4 MB (megabytes) / 25.1 MiB (mebibytes)
```

Comment: This looks to be related: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=780570

Answer (score 2):

When using `du` and you're comparing the results from 2 different runs against file systems you need to make sure to use the switch `--apparent-size`.

#### Example

Here's a CIFS mounted share.

```
$ du -sh somedir
50M somedir

$ du -sh --apparent-size somedir
45M somedir
```

*excerpt from du man page*

```
--apparent-size
          print  apparent  sizes,  rather than disk usage; although the apparent 
          size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in (‘sparse’)
          files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
```

#### So what's up?

This confuses a lot of people but remember that when files are stored to a disk they consume blocks of space even if they're only using a portion of those blocks. When you run `du` without the `--apparent-size` you're getting the size based on the amount of disk's block space used, not the actual space consumed by the file(s).

#### What about the 0B size?

> 0B     /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist

This is most likely a link. Doing this command will show if this is the case.

```
$ ls -l /Applications/Safari.app/Contents | grep Info.plist
```

Comment: man page from which OS ?

Comment: @AntoineLecaille from Linux, unfortunately, BSD `du` (which is what OSX uses) [doesn't have](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/du.1.html) that option.

Comment: @AntoineLecaille - look for a switch to your `du` that specifies something regarding "apparent" or "size". You can always install the GNU version of du too.

Comment: @sim Why are you talking about a remotely mounted file system ? Both directories are on /, an HFS+ filesystem.

Comment: @AntoineLecaille - Sorry I'll take those out of the A. I missed your osx tag but what I said still applies, whether local or remote.

Comment: @AntoineLecaille - updated answer. Also I found a duplicate Q (see above under your Q) for this exact same Q.

Comment: @terdon - same problem still applies but thanks for making me notice that. I completely missed this was a OSX box, I thought  he was mounting HFS+ remotely 8-)

Comment: But why would `du` give a different result in 2 directories on the _same_ partition/filesystem?

Comment: @terdon - one reason would be that if the files were consuming portions of multiple blocks. `du` would report the fragmented directory as larger than the copy. When you copy the files from one location on disk to another the system has the opportunity to do a "defrag" and consolidate the files data into fewer blocks.

Comment: This doesn't explain why du is reporting a size of zero.

Comment: @AntoineLecaille - the other thing I've seen with OSX is those .plist files are just links. Can you confirm if this is the actual file or a link to some other file? That would explain the 0 size.

Comment: @AntoineLecaille try it again without the `-h` option. Does it still show `0`?

Comment: @terdon This is not a link, unless ls lies to me.. And still 0 without -h. I think there is an utility mentionned in the book OS X and iOS internals that dumps info from an HFS+ fs.

Comment: @AntoineLecaille try `stat` and [let's continue this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux).

Comment: @slm This question is not duplicate of the other question. It is HFS+ specific. The other question does not have the answer to this question. Feel free to reformulate the question so that it does not sound as a duplicate.

Comment: @AntoineLecaille - yes I realized that after you posted your answer, I was waiting for it to get voted as a dup so we could vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is inline with others, but I can't comment yet so I get to start new:

Most files in /Applications are compressed and when you copy it that is lost.  When compression is used in HFS+ the files data is stored in the Resource Fork **OR** an extended attribute if it's small enough ( less than 4k).  If it's in a resource fork du (at least on Yosemite) will show it's actual disk usage in blocks.  If it's entirely in the attribute it will show 0.